# Geofence with pymavlink or dronekit-python

Tags: python, arduino, dronekit-python, mavlink

I'm trying to set fence for the copter using dronekit-python.I found command `MAV_CMD_NAV_FENCE_CIRCLE_INCLUSION` in [this document](http://mavlink.org/messages/common#GLOBAL_POSITION_INT_COV).

But it doesn't work when I use the `vehicle.message_factory.command_long_send` (which is the function `command_long_send` in class MAVLink from the file ardupilotmega.py actually ), I cannot find `mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_FENCE_CIRCLE_INCLUSION` either (so I use integer 5003 directly).

After reading the source code of ardupilotmega.py, I found that there is a function called `fence_point_send`, so can anyone tell me how to use it? How can I set the geofence just like [what Misson Planner do](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/ac2_simple_geofence.html) with python?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this command **[MAV_CMD_DO_FENCE_ENABLE](http://mavlink.org/messages/common)** to enable or disable geo-fence.
geo-fence has two parameters.

1. FENCE_ALT_MAX: The maximum altitude that the vehicle can reach.
2. FENCE_RADIUS : The maximum circle radius the vehicle can move in.

To change the parameters in code, you should use a function like [PARAM_SET](http://mavlink.org/messages/common#PARAM_SET) and pass the name and value for the parameter.

P.S: You can do all that using GCS like Mission Planner, APM Planner2 or Mavproxy.